# Review completion does not always show as S (simultaneous dates) with corrosponding action

Tags: bug, review, timestamps

When 2 or more history items occur at the same time, hovering over the timestamp should show an S next to all of the simultaneous actions. Example:

[image: History]

In this example, the *First answers* review task was created at the same time as the answer was posted, by hovering over either timestamp.

However, there is a bug where the system fails to recognize simultaneous dates, if one of those dates is the completion of a review task, and the other is an action corresponding to the review task. In this example, hovering over completion date of the *Share feedback x 1* should show as simultaneous to the added date of the Community comment. But it does **not**.

Similarly, hovering over the timestamp of a *Left closed in review* item fails to show as simultaneous with the completion time of the review task.

[image: History Reopen Votes]

This bug does **not** occur with *Suggested edits* review tasks.

[image: Suggested edit]

Comment: This is somewhat common when actions occur too far apart from each other. If you hover over the timestamps, they didn't occur at the same time, but actually 1 second apart. We don't actually group actions together that occurred due to the same event. What we actually do is select all the dates that appear multiple times in the timeline, and then mark those events as simultaneous whenever the event's date appears in that list. I'm sure there's a duplicate for this somewhere.

Comment: @animuson But what causes the 1 second discrepency between when the review action is performed and when the review task is marked as completed? And why does that occur for some review queues (e.g. Reopen votes) but not others (e.g. Suggested edits)?

Comment: It takes time for code to run. Sometimes the next call has fallen over to the next second. That's just kinda how time works.

Comment: @animuson To my experience, this seems to consistently happen with Reopen votes and others but not Suggested edits. And it happens even when I hover over the completion date of one and the other and the seconds are the same. If it were random chance I'd see at least some suggested edits with this bug or reopen/close votes without.

Comment: That wouldn't be surprising given there is a lot more processing that occurs when reopening or closing a question. But not displaying the indicator for truly identical dates shouldn't be possible. I checked your first example, and the dates were indeed 1 second apart and thus not eligible. You'd need to provide an example of where that actually happened, otherwise there's nothing to investigate.

Comment: @animuson [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77055247/timeline), I see a timestamp ending in `57Z` (which I assume the `57` is seconds) for both completion of the review task and the closure, but they don't display as simultaneous.

Comment: @animuson How much processing occurs when leaving a question closed in review though?

Comment: You should edit your question to focus on that example and the matching timestamps. :) I'm not familiar with how many things occur with the conclusion of every review type. But it's possible for it to occur on any review. If the code starts processing at, say, the .99 second mark, it would only have .01 seconds to do everything before the second changed. Going into the details of different review types taking longer to process isn't super productive. There's not really anything we can do about that.